# Finding the error in Xcode's project.pbxproj after merge

Tags: xcode, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm facing a complicated merge of two branches in my iOS app's version control. After I've gone through identifying and picking the conflicting lines in `project.pbxproj`, Xcode won't load the file. Running it through `plutil` shows this:

> CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary.

I've reverted and attempted the merge (carefully) a couple of times, and each time get the same results although I can't see where I'm introducing a format problem.

Is there a tool I can use to find out at least which *line* or *object* the error is in so that I can find the mistake I'm making?

Comment: Were you using Xcode 4's SCM integration (which more intelligently handles project file SCM management) to handle the merge? If not, that's worth a shot. Also, what SCM system are you using? These two bits of info could lead to an answer to your problem if not your exact question. :-)

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I'm using git, and no, not Xcode's SCM tool. It doesn't offer a "merge" option, just "pull" and "commit" ;-)

Comment: I believe Xcode's "Pull" with Git begets a merge: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-repositories_organizer/PullingUpdatesfromaRemoteRepository/PullingUpdatesfromaRemoteRepository.html

Comment: It wouldn't do it (it thinks there's pending changes in the workspace...which my workspace disagrees with). I've gone for the "accept theirs and add my files in" approach, but none of this addresses my question of whether it's possible to lint OPENSTEP-style property list files :-)

Comment: Here's how merge is done: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-repositories_organizer/MergingTwoBranches/MergingTwoBranches.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010350-CH10-SW1

Comment: Ah. I see. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3):

I created the following test:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <err.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:argv[1] length:strlen(argv[1])];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        if (!data)
            errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "open failed: %s\n", argv[1]);

        NSString *errorString;
        id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
                                                    mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                              format:NULL
                                                    errorDescription:&errorString];


        if (!plist)
            errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s\n", [errorString UTF8String]);

        printf("plist successfully read\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and ran it with a modified project.pbxproj:

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
        archiveVersion = 1;
        classes = {
                x = 1
        };
...
```

and got the following error:

2012-05-11 20:51:14.381 plist-test[41890:303] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 6. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.

Comment: That looks great :). I'll reproduce my Xcode issue and see what happens.

Comment: It doesn't find this problem, unfortunately. "2012-05-12 11:25:31.389 Untitled 2[1412:707] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary.
Untitled 2: Unexpected character / at line 1" Still, it's a useful trick to have up one's sleeve :)

Comment: You are right, Lion doesn't report the line number. Can you send me the file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already considered this, but the only option I see is writing a quick utility.

You could try `CFPropertyListIsValid()` and hope it spits out something useful. The header says:

> The debugging library version spits out some messages to be helpful.

Maybe this function could give you a bit more insight in its logging activity? I don't know what Apple considers "helpful" or what "some" means (maybe just, "Nope. It's invalid." along with returning `false`), but that'd be my next try.

Additionally, `CFPropertyListCreateWithStream()` may be helpful if you read a bit at a time. You could use it to zero in on the location of the error by feeding it in parts until it returns NULL. Cutting down the size when NULL is encountered would get you ever closer to its point of indigestion.